# Languages to choose for parallel computing

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

Just want to start a very general discussion taking your experienced opinion about which language/s should one foray into in order to get some sort of native parallel programming support now or atleast in future. I keep my question intentionally very abstract coz I would love to hear from variety of people on how they have began leveraging multicores in their software.

Best,
-Abhi

Comment: I don't think open-ended discussions are popular here on SO, at least not anymore.

Comment: There is no right answer to this question or silver bullet for parallel computing. The language you choose will depend primarily on the skill-set of your team and the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134867/which-programming-language-makes-concurrent-programming-as-easy-as-possible

Answer (score 2):

Go is Google's new Open Source concurrent language. I expect that, because it is Open Source and supported by Google, it will become a very popular language for parallel programming.

Take a look at the concurrent pi example here: http://golang.org/